# OpenVPN connection to Azure VPN point-to-site (p2s)

Tags: openvpn, azure

I create on my Azure Cloud the VPN Gateway and VPN point-to-site (p2s), I downloaded the VPN Client and after X hours to configure it, I cannot access to VPN.

Now, my questions is : is it possible connect to Azure VPN p2s with OpenVPN client ?

If yes, how?

Comment: No you cant use openVPN client. What is exactly your problem. "Cannot access to VPN" doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible connect to Azure VPN p2s with OpenVPN client ?

In brief, no. I've tested in my lab.

Azure P2S VPN only support Windows client for now.

=================================================================

Update:

As a workaround, you can deploy the VPN server on an Azure VM. If most of your clients are Windows-based, then please try to install the Windows Server and enable RRAS on it.

**Note:** If you deploy a VPN server on an Azure VM, please enable the outgoing NAT on it. Otherwise, the VPN clients can not access any resource on the VNET.

Because the IP address of client is allocated by the VPN server, which is unknown to Azure. Azure won't forward any packets from unknown source. With outgoing NAT enabled, all VPN clients are able to access resources on the VNET with the private IP address of the VPN server.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried. The only way to connect with OpenVPN, is create a VM and install a OpenVPN server.

There are also a lot incompatibility with Window$ 7 / 8 / 10 with VPNClient 32 or 64 bit release by them.

Comment: My best solution is open a second sub-domain "vpn.mydomain.com" and redirect on the VM with OpenVPN server.

Need to configure your load-balander to manage all with only 1 public IP.

Comment: @GiorgioDesideri I've updated my answer. If you choose to deploy a VPN server on the Azure VM, please enable outgoing NAT on the VPN server. Otherwise, the user defined route need to be involved.

Comment: @ Steven Lee - MSFT, thanks for details. I already did, but I didn't mention to not enter inside details of management. However, thanks.